# Is it possible to include calls to the Microsoft Graph API from within a Windows Service application?

Tags: service, microsoft-graph-api

We currently have a web application which requires manual intervention in order to initiate the transfer of data ***from*** Azure Active Directory (via the Microsoft Graph API) ***to*** a local SQL Server database instance for archival and reporting purposes.  This manual process is often run multiple times per day.

Our goal is to automate this data transfer process through use of a Windows service application; however, we have encountered an issue with instantiation of the Microsoft Graph client.  The vast majority of the documentation available seems to presume the use of Microsoft Graph with a user interface (which the service app doesn't employ).  Methods which work quite nicely with the typical MVC-based C# web application don't sit well within the more limited confines of a Windows service app.

Is this type of automation possible?  If so, is there any sort of documentation available regarding the use of Microsoft Graph within a Windows service app?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a documentation where is described how to call Graph API from a background service or daemon app without any user interaction. The same way will work for Windows service.

Documentation

[Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)